# Detect infinite loops in lua table crawling

Tags: c, api, recursion, lua, self-reference

I'm trying to crawl through the global namespace and all its contents with the lua c api.  One issue I'm running into is self-reference in tables. I was using a flattened table approach to determine if an entry exists, but this fails for nested numerical tables such as:

```
a = {[1] = {[1]={[1]=true}}}
```

Where the keyname of 1 will false trigger a duplicate entry since it occurs multiple times.  To circumvent this, I adopted the approach of using lua_topointer and storing the references in a mapping and checking this like so (where varUnit is just a structure to keep track of what variables have been loaded):

```
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
    const void* kp = lua_topointer(L, -1);
    var->kpointer = kp;
    varUnit->addPointer(kp);
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    lua_pushvalue(L, -2);
    const void* vp = lua_topointer(L, -1);
    var->vpointer = vp;
    varUnit->addPointer(vp);
    lua_pop(L, 1);
```

Then I check later on if that variable exists and if so I stop walking down the table.  However, this has not stopped infinite recursion when dealing with self-referencing tables.  Is there a better approach/some flawed logic here?  Is the 2nd encounter of a given table going to give me a different pointer?  I've seen multiple lua-based ways to crawl tables, but not any c based.

Edit:
Closed question, was a dumb mistake where I was checking for the pointer being a duplicate before assigning the pointer to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "using a flattened table approach"; but somewhere in your code you must check if a given value is a table (so you can check inside it).  The easiest would be to keep a set of all already visited tables, and for one you found, first check if it's already there so you don't crawl it twice.

Comment: This doesn't work.  A flattened table of the above example would be something like: (a,1,1,1) for the rightmost table.  This fails because key names are not unique.  This is why I used pointers since I presume every value has a unique & persistent (to the current scope) pointer, which for reasons unknown to me isn't working.

Comment: AFAICT, a "flattened table" (whatever that means) can't have loops in it.  are you flattening them yourself? or you get them already flattened?  if the first, then there's where you should detect loops (or the flattening wouldn't success); if the latter, then it shouldn't be your problem.